# Where to find synaptics mouspad gesture installation packages

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I stumbled upon following [web page](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/touchpad-linux)  and was immediately interested in the mousepad gesture possibilities. However I can't find any installation package (not in the software center, nor in synaptic). Anyone an idea where the installation packages can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

This software is not available in the Ubuntu-packages. 
However it could be that it's available in [this site (click here)](http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/)

Mind you: installing software from unofficial sites or recourses could compromise your system.